# How to make hair particles not colliding each other

Tags: objects, particles, hair

I am currently kinda need your help,

I am currently making a leaf on a stem for my Blend project.
To achieve that, I use particle system (hair) with leaf object as Render Object.  And I also want to do some hair dynamics.

Hi guys, I am currently kinda need your help,

I have two problems that I face right now:

1. When I do the hair dynamics, the object center will displace from the original vertex.
2. The hair (which is Leaf Object) will intersect each other.

My questions are:

1. How to prevent the hair particles to not misplaced from the original vertices spawn point?
2. How to make the leaf object not intersect each other?

Here are the video link to make clear my problem: https://youtu.be/GLmIo4B9vUA

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question is to move the leaf object's origin point to the base of the leaf, or whatever point you'd like it to emit from once you set up the particle system. As for the second part of your question I asked the same thing yesterday here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219632/how-do-i-enable-collision-with-a-hair-particle-system-to-deform-each-particles I haven't been able to work this out yet, I think it may be possible by adding a Particle Instance modifier to your object (leaf) but I haven't been able to get it to work as desired.

Comment: Hey there @Aubrey thanks for the answer. Apparently I already had my objects origin placed to the base of the leave. But darn it get misplaced everywhere when the simulation start. 
But anyway I will try to redo it. I actualy had redone it once with different object (simple thin pyramid with object origin placed at the pyramid bottom) and it actually worked fine, but not with my leaves XD.

Anyway thanks in advance, I also want to follow up your question as well :D.

Have a good day!

Comment: in your linked video I can't see what you are trying to do, or what you have done to your leaves. You have applied physics of some sort to your leaves, so when you run the animation, they are falling with gravity, have you tried adding collision and soft body to them? Perhaps you could add your blend file here, with a gif, and some detail to your question, what you're trying to do, and what you have done already. As for your 2nd question and mine as linked above, deforming the mesh of particle instances, I'm still looking for an answer, maybe the new geometry node is a way.